# Why are designated initializers not implemented in g++

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, designated-initializer

Is there any specific reason why has support for designated initializers not been added to g++? Is the reason that C99 standards came late and g++ was developed earlier and later people didn't care about this issue, or there is some inherent difficulty in implementing designated initializers in the grammar of C++?

Comment: Linux is written in C and not C++. g++ is the frontend for C++, use gcc for C.

Comment: g++ is a C++ compiler. Use gcc.

Comment: We have re written some portion of linux kernel in C++, so it is essential for us to use g++

Comment: @Bharat Singh: Using C++ in the Linux kernel is a very, very bad idea. Linux lacks all the infrastructure required to make C++ work properly. Linus Torvalds explained this multiple times in detail: http://kerneltrap.org/node/2067

Comment: We have an implementation of the linux OS in C++, with the core kernel in C with some external wrapper functions providing support for the OO external hardware drivers. Just tell me is it possible to modify gcc so that it supports designated initializers in C++

Comment: Compile C files with a C compile and C++ files with a C++ compiler. Designated initializers work perfectly well in C but they are not valid in C++.

Comment: I want to know the reason why are they not supported by C++

Comment: Why don't you just compile the C parts of the kernel with the C compiler, your C++ parts with `g++`, then link together the result?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I noted in a comment, G++ doesn't support C99 standard designated initialisers, but it does support the GNU extension to C90 which allows designated initialisers.  So this doesn't work:

```
union value_t {
    char * v_cp;
    float v_f;
};
union value_t my_val = { .v_f = 3.5f };
```

But this does:

```
union value_t my_val = { v_f: 3.5f };
```

This seems to be a bad interaction of co-ordination between the C and C++ standards committees (there is no particularly good reason why C++ doesn't support the C99 syntax, they just haven't considered it) and GCC politics (C++ shouldn't support C99 syntax just because it's in C99, but it should support GNU extension syntax that achieves exactly the same thing because that's a GNU extension that can be applied to either language).

Comment: this is no longer true in g++-5.2 and probably going all the way back at least to g++-4.8

Answer (score 13):

I ran into this same problem today. g++ with -std=c++11 and c++14 does support designated initializers, but you can still get a compilation error "test.cxx:78:9: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported" if you don't initialize the struct in the order in which it's members have been defined. As an example

```
struct x
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

// This is correct
struct x x_1 = {.a = 1, .b = 2};
// This will fail to compile with error non-trivial designated initializer
struct x x_2 = {.b = 1, .a = 2};
```

Comment: Designated initializers still aren't part of any version of standard C++.

Comment: @Quentin Corrected now.

Comment: @Qu9entin: Designated initializers are part of C++20. So yes, finally, they are arriving.

Answer (score 8):

C++ does not support this. It will not even be in the C++0x standards it seems: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/browse_thread/thread/8b7331b0879045ad?pli=1

Also, why are you trying to compile the Linux kernel with G++?

Comment: We have re written some portion of linux kernel in C++, so it is essential for us to use g++

Comment: Wait till Linus hears about it.

Answer (score 5):

It is [officially supported in C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers), and is [already implemented in g++8.2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B2a_features) (even without the `std=c++2a` flag).

Answer (score 2):

As of at least g++-4.8 this is now supported by default.

Answer (score -3):

Accoding to
http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html
designated initializers have been already implemented.

What version of g++ do you use? (Try g++ -- version)

Comment: That's C99, not C++. I don't think every C99 feature is implicitly supported by g++.

Comment: Maybe you do not use "C mode"

Comment: The poster wants C99 constructs in C++,  which is completely wrong.

Comment: i don't want C99 constructs, i want to know the reason why they are not supported in C++, if there is some valid reason why they are not supported, there would me no point for me spending time in changing gcc.

Comment: Put very simply, C and C++ are two different languages with different standards.  Mostly the C++ standard includes everything in the C standard, but designated initialisers is one thing that is in the C99 standard but not any of the C++ standards.  So G++ correctly implements the C++ standard by not including designated initialisers.

Comment: But note that G++ **does** support the GNU C extension - use `{ m_f: 3.5f}` instead of `{ .m_f = 3.5f }`.  It's not portable, but it works in G++.