# assignment by index or field doesn't work in C++

Tags: c++

```
static struct inet_protosw inetsw_array[] =
{
    [0] = { /* assignment by index */
      .type =       SOCK_STREAM, /* assignment by field */
      .protocol =   IPPROTO_TCP,
      .prot =       &tcp_prot,
      .ops =        &inet_stream_ops,
      .no_check =   0,
      .flags =      INET_PROTOSW_PERMANENT |
              INET_PROTOSW_ICSK,
    },
}
```

The above code works in C, but not in C++. I think the 2 methods are really nice. How C++ remove it?

PS: It seems field assignment can be accomplished by:
type: SOCK_STREAM

Comment: More on this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900739/why-are-designated-initializers-not-implemented-in-g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly the `[0]` and `.type` initialization designators have been introduced by ISO C99, and since the C++ standard came out in 1998, it didn't incorporate these features.

And also in C++11 it is not possible. The relevant section in the standard is *8.5.1 Aggregates*, and all the examples in that section are without designators.

Answer (score 4):

C and C++ are different languages. This code sample uses object initialization features that exist in C and do not exist in C++.

It's not that "C++ removed it", it's that it was not part of C back when C++ branched from it.

Comment: Yes. These 2 features are added in new version gcc