# Statically initialize nested C++ structures with named labels using g++

Tags: c++, g++

I am importing/porting existing C code to C++.  I am hoping to make as few changes to the existing body of code as possible to minimize preterbing the existing code.
This code makes use of static named initialization of nested structures.  For quick made up example:

```
Car car =
{
  .color = RED,
  .tire.tread = OLD,
  .tire.diameter = 27.106,
  .tire.material.type = RUBBER,
  .tire.material.density = 700,
};
```

I figured out that [these are called designated initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900739/why-are-designated-initializers-not-implemented-in-g).

I learned about [GNU initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601201/c-struct-initialization-using-labels-it-works-but-how) but I haven't figured out how to implement hierarchy with it.

I read that [designated initializers are supported in g++ with c++11 enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38526699/1419054), but that didn't seem to work for me.

The code I am porting has pages of initialization with at least four layers deep of hierarchy.  So I am trying to look for a straightforward transformation which doesn't get too involved.

I am looking for one of these possible solutions:

- How to enable C99 designated initializers
- How to formulate hierarchical GNU style initialization
- What is a C++ equivalent way to do this which wouldn't be error prone transcribing war and peace.
- An obvious solution I haven't thought of

I am using g++ version

```
g++.exe (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
```

Comment: I have also tried -std=c++2a which also results in the error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of such *nested* designated initializers seems to be something of an edge case. The following works in both `clang-cl` (in Visual Studio 2019) and the native `MSVC` compiler (but the latter only with the `/std:c++latest` option, which uses the draft C++20 standard):

```cpp
struct inner {
    int x, y;
    double z;
};
struct outer {
    char a;
    double b;
    inner c;
};

outer my_outer = { .a = 'a', .b = 1.2, .c = { .x = 3, .y = 4, .z = 5.6 } };
```

With `clang-cl`, the initializer can be abbreviated to the following form:

```cpp
outer my_outer = { .a = 'a', .b = 1.2, .c.x = 3, .c.y = 4, .c.z = 5.6 };
```

but `MSVC` complains in this case, with:

> error C7558: nested member access is not allowed in standard C++
>   designated initializers; use a nested initializer list

So, for your example, you could try this:

```cpp
Car car =
{
  .color = RED,
  .tire = {
     .tread = OLD,
     .diameter = 27.106,
     .material.type = RUBBER,
     .material.density = 700,
   }
};
```

There's a helpful 'discussion' of the [topic on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), with this part being notable:

> ...each designator must name a direct non-static data member of T, and
>   all designators used in the expression must appear in the same order
>   as the data members of T.

Comment: `The following works in` .... and count in gcc9.2 with `-std=c++2a`.

Comment: I'll give gcc9.2 c++2a a shot

Comment: I was able to make it work with gcc9.2 with -std=c++2a if the notation is changed to the first example type with recursive braces.

Comment: Going back to gcc8.1 with -std=c++2a it looks like it also supports the multiple brace format as opposed to the multiple dot inline format